Homogeneity of Schroedinger equation implies norm conservation
I am trying to understand how homogeneity of Schroedinger equation implies norm conservation. I know that we are considering the non-relativistic case, where particle number is conserved, so we do not have creation or annihilation.
If the SE was non-homogenous and we would have:
$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi(\vec r,t)=D\psi(\vec r,t) + q$, where one can easily show that $D=\frac{-\hbar \nabla^2}{2m}$. Substituting the above expression in the time derivative of the norm:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\psi(\vec r,t)|^2=$$
$$-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\vec \nabla \vec j d\vec r +\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 2Re[q\psi^*]d\vec r$$.
If one were to apply Gauss law in the first integral then we have:
$-\int_F \vec j d\vec F$ where F is the surface.
In my lecture, it is said that this integral is zero because $\psi$ belongs to square-integrable functions. How is that the reason for the integral to be zero? Or what is the actual reason why is zero?

Square integrable functions $f(\vec{r})$ must go to zero as $|\vec{r}| \to 0$

Why and $|\vec r|$ is not going to zero. The volume integral is over all space, so the surface integral should be over all space. Instead $|\vec r|$ is going in infinity, no?

yes, that's a typo. I meant $|\vec{r}| \to \infty$.
